# my images do not show in my admin products page laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The image is in a folder called imagg. For example if I want to upload an image in the admin products page called (Digital_01.png) it will be (15678532232.png) or something like that.
Therefor it will not be displayed in the page
this is my AdminAddProductComponent code :

```
class AdminAddProductComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $name;
    public $slug;
    public $short_description;
    public $description;
    public $regular_price;
    public $sale_price;
    public $featured;
    public $quantity;
    public $stock_status;
    public $SKU;
    public $image;
    public $category_id;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->stock_status ='instock';
        $this->featured = 0;
    }

    public function generateSlug()
    {
        $this->slug = Str::slug($this->name,'-');
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->name = $this->name;
        $product->slug = $this->slug;
        $product->short_description = $this->short_description;
        $product->description = $this->description;
        $product->regular_price = $this->regular_price;
        $product->sale_price = $this->sale_price;
        $product->featured = $this->featured;
        $product->SKU = $this->SKU;
        $product->stock_status = $this->stock_status;
        $product->quantity = $this->quantity;
        $imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.'. $this->image->extension();
        $this->image->storeAs('products',$imageName);
        $product->image = $imageName;
        $product->category_id = $this->category_id;
        $product->save();
        session()->flash('message', 'Product has been added successfully !');
    }

    public function render()
    {

        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-add-product-component',['categories'=>$categories])->layout('layouts.admin-category');
    }
}
```

And this is the config/filesystem code :

```
 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
           // 'root' => storage_path('app'),
           'root' => public_path('imagg'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Comment: Are the images actually saved on the server? Have you checked that. If yes, how do you display them in the view?

Comment: @Cosmin I have checked on the server yes all the data are there but the images  that I've added in the admin products are not appropriate to the images names (564987563.png) like that

Comment: I don't understand you comment. You're expecting other name for a given image than what you set when saving the image?

Comment: I'm allowing this folder which contains the images to have the same name and different indexes for example (Digital_01.png - Digital_02.png ...) but in this case they are shown with numbers that's why I guess they are no displayed

Comment: If you're expecting Digital_01.png, Digital_02.png etc. you should update the code responsible for setting the image name. Right now you're building the name as such `$imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.'. $this->image->extension();`.

Comment: @Cosmin how possibly I can do that ?

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a chapter on [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads) and especially on [Specifying A File Name](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your naming rules are and on what they are based on, so what you have to do is to make sure you follow those rules when you build the image name in `$imageName`. If you're building the image based on the product slug, you can use the slug as a starting point for the image name and then append a number to it (something like [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-file-exists-append-number-to-name/)).