# the image I uploaded unto the admin database of products doesn't appear in my page laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

My Images are stored in a folder in public folder called imagg
The images are displayed in the admin database of products but do not show in the main page of products .
This is the naming of images in the productFactory.php:

`'image' => 'digital_'.$this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,22)`

this is the filesystem.php :

```
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),

        ],
```

The admin-product-component.blade.php :

```
 @foreach ($products as $product)
          <tr>
                 <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
                 <td><img src="{{asset('imagg')}}/{{$product->image}}" width="60"></td>
@endforeach
```

Also the pictures names are different when I uploaded them(digital_1.png for example is now like 156251515154.png)
how to solve this ?

Comment: From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974961/my-images-do-not-show-in-my-admin-products-page-laravel): you name the file `$imageName = Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.'. $this->image->extension();`

Comment: @brombeer how to make the name appropriate to the others and eventually will appear